URL search params showing as object in browser
The code is as follows
newParams = new URLSearchParams({...{sort:{title: "desc"}}})

But it is showing as object in the url.
On debugging when i convert newParams to string it outputs 'sort=%5Bobject+Object%5D' and this is exactly what is displayed on browserl url.

newParams.toString() = 'sort=%5Bobject+Object%5D'

I am expecting the url to be something like "sort%5Btitle%5D=desc"
Can somebody tell what is the issue here?
Any help would be appreciated.

[object Object] appears when you convert an object to a string.   javascript doesn't know how to convert your object, so outputs [object Object].  If you want some specific format, then you'll need to convert it to that format.
